# Missing data in BigQuery database paired to GA4 after 90 days

Tags: database, google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I have connected GA4 data to BigQuery with default Google connector. I have found that events table stopped saving after 90 days and I have not data for last week, because to this day I see as last day 2023-10-07.

I know that BigQuery should save data after 90 days to "long-term storage" but I cant find them, I dont know, where is this 90days+ data. Also I cant find any settings where I should set some rules for saving.

Am I able to set unlimited saving for events from GA4? How can I access this 90days+ data which I cant see? If the data were lost, shpuld I recover them?

Thank you very much for helping!

Comment: The problem still persists, does anyone know what to do with it?